# How does {$variable} works in PHP?

Tags: php, string, variables, interpolation

When I want to use a variable value within a string, I connect them with . (dot) operator.

I see that some people use {$variable} within a string instead.

So..my example:

```
"my name is ".$variable
```

some people use it:

```
"my name is {$variable}"
```

What is the difference between above two examples?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's used when you want to append a string to the value in the variable inside a string.

```
$variable = 'hack';

// now I want to append 'ed' to $variable:    

echo "my name is {$variable}";   // prints my name is hack

echo "my name is {$variable}ed"; // prints my name is hacked

echo "my name is $variable";     // prints my name is hack

echo "my name is $variableed";   // Variable $variableed not defined.
```

Comment: // Thank you for your input. What is name of it? Do we call it as block or..?

Comment: [The manual calls it the "Curly syntax", which is entirely accurate.](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)

Comment: It's also useful even in unambiguous situations. For example, my IDE for whatever reason can highlight the interpolated variable only if braces are used.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe some examples will explain the brackets and the . operator to concatenate strings.

Lets say you have a variable holding some value which is say $money and you want to display this amount.

```
$money=10;

print "you have earned $money"; // would output 'you have earned 10;
// ops missed the dollar sign as we are dealing with currency.
print "you have earned $$money"; // hmmm, that wont work $$ means something else.
```

So if you have curly braces then you can tell PHP which variable you want substituted into the string a lot more clearly.

```
print "you have earned ${$money}.00"; would now output 'you have earned $10.00'
```

Now that looks a lot nicer.